Probability that one expectation is larger than another expectation using MC estimate
Consider an expectation $a=\int f(\boldsymbol{x})p(\boldsymbol{x})d\boldsymbol{x}$ and an expectation $b=\int g(\boldsymbol{x})q(\boldsymbol{x})d\boldsymbol{x}$.
For a given small number of samples $f(\boldsymbol{x}_i), \boldsymbol{x}_i \sim p(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $g(\boldsymbol{x}_j), \boldsymbol{x}_j \sim q(\boldsymbol{x})$, is there a non-parametric way to calculate a probability $P(b>a)$?

Please tell us what you know or assume about $p$ and $q,$ because there are large families of techniques that vary according to such information.  Are these samples independent of each other?

Thank you for the quick response! The samples are independent and $p$ and $q$ are from the same family of distributions. But the samples are not necessarily normally distributed.

Since $a$ and $b$ are numbers and not random variables, what is the meaning of $P(b>a)$? On principle, it is either zero or one.

Sorry about the bad notation and confusion. $a$ and $b$ are not available, but only a small number of samples $\boldsymbol{x}_i \sim p(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $\boldsymbol{x}_j \sim q(\boldsymbol{x})$ to calculate Monte Carlo estimates $\hat{a}=\sum_i f(\boldsymbol{x}_i)$ and $\hat{b}=\sum_j g(\boldsymbol{x}_j)$. So I would like to obtain a probability $P(\hat{b}>\hat{a})$ as a confidence measure for $b>a$.
